How to copy files in recursive manner to flattened sink folder with filename generated as source foldernames spearated by a delimiter in ADF pipeline
We have a requirement to copy files using azure data factory from one Azure storage account with a specific folder hierarchy (3 level and 4 level- both types of hierarchy structure) to another storage account (with different access permissions) with a flattened folder structure with file names prefix from source folder names.
For example if from storage account A, Container B, the file C is copied from B/x/y/z/C path then the destination filename would be x__y__z__C inside sink container.
The file size may be large files (>10 GB) or small files.
If anyone has any idea / done similar implementation any help would be appreciated.
I have tried with Get Metadata in a foreach loop but it was not working since there are multiple hierarchies.
Also since file names should not be default ADF provided flatten hierarchy feature could not be used.
Following are pictures of my configuration and json after I tried approach suggested by RakeshCopySourceSinkCacheSink
DatasetSourceSink

Get meta data activity won't give the files list recursively. First you need to get all the file paths. You can do that by using ADF dataflow.
For sample, these are my source files with structure:
mysourcedata
    x
        y
            Table2.csv
            userdata1.parquet
            z
                file1.json
                sample_blank.csv

First, create a delimited dataset with file path till only the container and uncheck the First row as header.

Create a dataflow with above dataset as source. In the source settings, give the wild card file path like below **/* and add a column for the file name.

This will merge all the files rows and adds a column which consists of that row's filepath.

Next, take an aggregate transformation and group by filepath column. In the aggregate section, create any sample column count with expression count(filepath).

This will make a column with all required file paths.

Take a select transformation and delete the extra column count. After that, take a derivedColumn transformation to create a new column targetpath. This column will generate the required target filename.
Expressions:
targetpath - replace(dropLeft(filepath,1),'/','__')
filepath - dropLeft(filepath,1)


At last, add sink cache and select the Write to activity output checkbox.
Now, in pipeline, take a dataflow activity and add the above dataflow. In the dataflow activity, select None for the Logging level and go to Sink properties -> uncheck First row only.
If debug the pipeline, the dataflow will give the required columns as JSON array in its output.

Use this array in a loop and copy from the source file path and create target file with required name.
Give this array to a For-Each activity using below expression.
@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value

Inside For-Each, take a copy activity Binary datasets for both source and sink. In both datasets, give the path till the containers. Create a string parameter and use that in the filename of the datasets as @dataset().<parameter_name>.
Pass the required source file path @item().filepath to the source dataset parameter.

And, pass @item().targetpath to the sink dataset parameter.

Now, debug the pipeline and the required target files will be generated.


Thanks Rakesh.  It is working till Foreach input but not copying files to sink. I am getting input of Foreach activity as {
"ItemsCount": "4"
}
Have already set @item().filepath and @item().targetpath to source and sink respectively. Ami I missing something?

Is it giving any error? Can you show your source and sink datasets and copy activity source and sink configurations?

ErrorCode=UserErrorSourceBlobNotExist,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The required Blob is missing. Please contact Blob Storage team if you need further support. ContainerName: https://testcontainer.blob.core.windows.net/test-source-folder, path:folder1%20/%20folder2%20/%200folder3/xyz%20.pdf.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.,Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,StorageExtendedMessage=

Can you provide your source and sink dataset configurations and copy activity source and sink configuration and sink cache array? I think you have given the dataset parameter to the folder path in the dataset. You need to give it to the file path in the dataset.

Added pictures for these configurations above. I have given dataset parameter to filepath in both source and sink but it is giving error while trying to read

Does your file names actually contains those %20s in between? or are those spaces ' ' in between words? If those are spaces, I think Dataflow added '%20''s in place of spaces. So, in the derived column use replace(replace(dropLeft(filepath,1),'/','__'),'%',' '). Replace the same for the another column as well.

Same issue after changing it , this is for character encoding, so i think it is fine to have that. Need to split filename and foldername and pass separately into dataset. Do you have the folderpath expression  which can effectively extract from total folderpath+filename ?

It will work even when passing total filepath in a single filename parameter. If your normal copy activity identifies the file with spaces, then the special charcters are the issue, try like this replace(replace(dropLeft(filepath,1),'/','__'),'%20',' '). Also check your filepath with %20 characters by hardcoding in the copy activity filename. If it gives the same error then thats the issue.

yes, this urlencoding is happening automatically and so it is unable to read paths. Without this encoding in simple copy activity works but with this urlencoding simple copy activity is also failing. Could not find any option in adf to urldecode before copy activity tries to read files from blob.

I see you have raised another question, I will check that.
